# Background-image seems to be filtered in Sitefinity 4

Tags: css, background, background-image, sitefinity

I have a CSS class with a fully qualified image url like:

```
div.main { background: #fffff url('http://www.domain.com/images/pixel.gif') no-repeat  0 0; }
```

The markup is:

```
<div class="main">content here</div>
```

In Firebug, the computed css says:

```
div.main {}
```

Answer (score 4):

You've specified `#fffff` as the `background-color` - but that only has 5 hex digits, so it's *invalid*.

Due to the invalid `background-color`, Firefox is ignoring the whole `background` declaration.

Change it to `#ffffff` (or simply `#fff`) and it will work.